# UINavigationBar and Status Bar on iOS7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7, statusbar

How to make so that the color has changed color status bar when you open another controller.

An illustrative example made ​​on facebook for iOS 7:

[image]

Comment: What's your meaning? what actually you want?

Comment: I solved this question.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar color is always the same as you can see. What is changing here is just the background color of your View Controller. 
If you have 2 controllers with a different background color you should already have this effect.